# How to use ASE bulk copy into c#

Tags: c#, sybase, bulkinsert, sap-ase

How to use ASE Bulk Copy in c# to insert data into Sybase

I tried this code,

```
            AseBulkCopy f = new AseBulkCopy(con);
            f.BatchSize = 10000;

            string query;
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
            {
                query = "insert into Sample3 values("+i+",'dd')";
                AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand(query,con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Insertion Complete");
            con.Close();
```

But it take same time as general please suggest any solution I am new about that

Comment: It doesn't look like you use the `AseBulkCopy` class at all.

Comment: give any example for how to use bulk copy

Comment: No idea...I can't find documentation at all...but it is clear from your code you aren't calling it at all.

Answer (score 0):

AseBulkCopy is used to insert rows from a C# datatable to a database table.
Check the below code:

```
AseBulkCopy obj_AseBulkCopy = new AseBulkCopy(db_Conn);
obj_AseBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "db_Table";
obj_AseBulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
db_Conn.Open();
obj_AseBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt_DataTable);
db_Conn.Close();
```

Using the above code, you will be able to insert all the rows present in the `dt_DataTable` to `db_table` in the database.